# What is super(props) doing for my React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not great with JS and playing around with React.

The React docs located [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor) state the following:

> When implementing the constructor for a `React.Component` subclass, you
>   should call `super(props)` before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   `this.props` will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.

My question is HOW does this actually work?  What is `super()` doing that magically enables `this.props` within my constructor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the documentation that you have mentioned. It is coded in ES6 standard of javascript.

So this statement

```
class Greeting extends React.Component
```

It means Greeting is inherting from `React.Component`, by calling `super`, you are actually calling the parent element with `props` parameter,

if you intend on using `this.props` inside the `constructor`, you have to call `super(props)`

Hope [these links](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/03/26/683329) are helpful.

Comment: why would anyone want to use `this.props` instead of just `props`, inside the constructor?

Comment: nvm, I realise `this.props` is necessary to use instead of `props` if you want to modify the props themselves.

Comment: @Magne note that you shouldn't modify props as they are [supposed to be immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

Comment: @KubaJastrz yeah, you're correct, but I was merely talking about setting `this.props = props` in the constructor, which is the only "exception" to that rule.